# Push Pull Switch Mode Power Supplies

Tags: power, transistors

I am reading this material for understanding the switch mode push pull power supplies. 
[Push Pull Switched Mode Power Supplies](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/PSU/psu34.php)

I am unable to understand the working though. Can someone provide a simple explanation for the circuit in 3.4.2 and its waveforms?

And it is mentioned as R3 and C2 are the timings components which I dont understand also. How do the internal transistors and the external transistors function? Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: If you haven't already, strongly recommend reading modules 1-3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

The working of the circuit is described here in [this document](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3524.pdf) which describes the functionality of PWM modulators.

RT and Ct are part of an oscillator circuit where

> \$ f = \frac{1.18}{R_T C_T}\$
>
> (Rt is in kΩ, Ct is in uF, f is in kHz)
>
> Practical values of CT fall between 1 nF and 100 nF. Practical values
>   of RT fall between 1.8 kW and 100 kW. This results in a frequency
>   range typically from 120 Hz to 500 kHz.

Source: datasheet listed above

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide a run through of the operation of the blocks during one on state and one off state?

Comment: And sorry for the basic question, how does the capacitor charge and discharge through the resistor. From where the R and C get the charge and discharge?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No I am trying to understand the working of the circuit

Comment: I am unable to understand how the RC section works. We will get a ramp waveform at the timing capacitor pin only when RC is connected in series, right? But here R and C are not in series. How is this ramp generated?

Comment: The oscillator section is not described in the documentation, nor does it need to be described. All a designer needs to know is that it generates a pulse at the specified frequency. It is most likely a circuit like a 555 timer. The RC section could be in series, or parallel